# SquareSpace Custom CSS; Title Block

Tags: css, size, block

I am pretty new to CSS and I am trying to add some custom code to my site. Below is my current custom code. The title text is centered, but how do I vertically center the title text as well?Also, I already tried `vertical-align: middle;` but that didn't do anything. Any help would be great!

```
.image-slide-title 
 display: block;
 position: relative;height: 100px;
 top: -15px;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0;
 background-color: #1E75BB;
 margin-bottom: 0px; 
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
 -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
 -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
 transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that CSS is CSS and the fact that it's used in a SquareSpace theme is not important. SquareSpace doesn't use and special proprietary style.

I would also suggest that you build out a tiny version of what you are attempting in a jsFiddle or CodePen (for every stack overflow post)

### html

```
<div class="example-area">

  <h2 class="example-text">
    Example text
  </h2>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.example-area {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.example-text {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.w-padding .example-text {
  padding: 100px 0; / *use padding to create size */
}

.w-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 231px; /* arbitrary example */
}
```

jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/d85r37ob/

It all depends on what you are doing / if there is a background image - if the size is explicit etc.

Keep in mind that if you use flex-box, you'll have to organize the browser prefixes for it. I suggest autoprefixr

Comment: Great thanks for the suggestions! I ended up using padding to fix it. Thanks again!

Comment: PS `vertical-align: middle;` is only for elements that are `display: inline-block;` - which is really handy - when you have more than one inline-block element and you want them to align vertically. : )

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding top to align center or use flex property or line height.

```
.image-slide-title{
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of vertical align add this

```
line-height: 100px;
```

and that's all!

one thing I noticed in your code that after image-slide-title you does not added {
so don't forget to add that.